# How to get all data without any filtering in "in" clause

Tags: postgresql

As a part of reporting I want to get some values from database. 
Also I included filtering in report UI, like :

`select * from invoice where id in (92)`

So I am making the postgres statement dynamically(here 92 is the value getting from UI and assigning dynamically). But I want to return all data without any condition if the user select no option, id in this case (no filtering). So how can I handle the "in" clause to return all data without any filtering in this case.

I am asking for a common term that can be included in 'in' clause, so it retun all rows without filtering.

Thanks!

Comment: Add a short-circuit condition, like: `select * from invoice where (1=1) OR id in (92)` (of course: based on your "user" parameter, instead of `(1=1)` )

Comment: `select * from invoice where (1=1) OR id in (inv_id)`. In case, if `inv_id` is zero, it becomes error, rit ?

Comment: Mys answer is basically the same as Gordon's. But since you didn't mention the stuff you get from the UI, I had to use pseudo-code. (gordon assumed v_id to be a parameter to the query)

Answer (score 1):

One method is using logic like:

```
where (v_id is null) or (id = v_id)
```

Note:  be careful about the use of `in`.  It probably will not do what you intend if you expect multiple values to match.